# AWS Glue: SQL Server multiple partitioned databases ETL into Redshift

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift, etl, database-partitioning, aws-glue

Our team is trying to create an ETL into Redshift to be our data warehouse for some reporting. We are using Microsoft SQL Server and have partitioned out our database into 40+ datasources. We are looking for a way to be able to pipe the data from all of these identical data sources into 1 Redshift DB.

Looking at AWS Glue it doesn't seem possible to achieve this. Since they open up the job script to be edited by developers, I was wondering if anyone else has had experience with looping through multiple databases and transfering the same table into a single data warehouse. We are trying to prevent ourselves from having to create a job for each database... Unless we can programmatically loop through and create multiple jobs for each database.

We've taken a look at DMS as well, which is helpful for getting the schema and current data over to redshift, but it doesn't seem like it would work for the multiple partitioned datasource issue as well.

Comment: Some of my colleagues had a similar problem and after not being impressed by Amazon Glue they ended up using Matillion. However I think they had to do some fancy logic to coalesce the data from multiple databases.

Comment: @ColdSolstice Thanks for the info, sad to hear they weren't able to utilize Amazon Glue but I will definitely look into Matillion. Do you know if they used this solution for more than just a data migration and used it to pipe constantly as a data warehouse?

Comment: SQL Server supports parititioning *and* columnstores too. Are you sure you need a new database instead of a better schema? What does 40 datasources mean? Why not a single data warehouse? Why not use  star schemas and columnstores?

Comment: Furthermore Redshift isn't magic. It's meant to *scale* to multi-TB data warehouses. That means it won't run fast as fast as expected in the single-digit GB scale but will run as fast in the TB scale provided you buy a large enough instance. It won't cover a bad design either. A star schema will perform faster than disjointed tables

Comment: And finally, Redshift is good at aggregate queries and ingesting lots (multi-GBs) of data from files that *already* have the appropriate form. It's *terrible* at ETL, where you add one row at a time. Think single digit rows per second. It's *terrible* at retrieving individual rows. In the first case it has to update the column buckets and dictionaries for each column in a row. And repeat it for each row. When retrieving rows, it has to unpack all buckets to retrieve the values that correspond to a single row

Comment: @LucasKlaassen how much data (GBs and rows) do you have and how many rows are added per day?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right that you must not use transaction ETL with redshift. But you are very wrong about running transformations inside redshift. Redshift is excellent for this! (not one row at a time of course - but entire tables being updated with new data that has been introduced - such as the case i describe below)

Comment: @JonScott wrong as in having real life experience and facing the consequences of bad decisions? Updating data is *bad* in any reporting database. That's why fact tables are used. *Adding* new data with COPY isn't `updating with new data`. Using Redshift as the *staging* instead of the reporting database is slower than using another database to work per row, or at least *costs* a lot more for the same performance. You *can* do ETL, but it will cost you a lot more than preparing the data in advance and using COPY

Comment: i have set this up a number of times and it is good. Take a look at how Matillion ETL works with redshift and how popular it is if you want proof. Anyway - if anyone is following this and wants the right answer for them, i suggest they try out a quick PoC using the various possible methods and select which is best for them.

Comment: by the way, generally i do not recommend matillion. Instead I prefer to hand code the ETL. I was just citing it to show that transformation inside Redshift not only works well, but is also very popular. see https://www.matillion.com/etl-for-redshift/faq/#performance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos great question, our goal is to be able to run some internal reports (mainly to extract aggregate data) out of our SQL Server databases. Right now 40 datasources means we have 1 database schema which we have partitioned out into 40 different databases to scale horizontally. Right now, in order to run a report across all of our clients we need to loop through each database and either do a query of queries on that data or do some nasty in memory computations. Having the ability to load specific tables from each database into 1 main internal reporting database is the goal.

Comment: @LucaKlaassen 1st) how much data are we talking about? Why 40 servers instead of more disks in the RAID array, or OLAP cubes, or columnstores? 2nd) SQL Server supports federated views since 2000. You can have one view that references the other tables and as long as they have the proper constraints, the optimizer knows to ask the appropriate linked table for data.

Comment: @LucasKlaassen on the other hand Lenovo published TPC-H results for a single instance 10TB data warehouse [almost 2 years ago](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/07/18/sql-server-2016-posts-world-record-tpc-h-10-tb-benchmark/). How much data do you have? In that range Redshift would cost [$10K-$55K per year](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for this break down, I'm going to take a look into federated views to see if that will work for us. Besides their [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187467(v=sql.105).aspx) do you know of any other good resources to look at?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an excellent use-case for Matillion ETL for Redshift.

*(Full disclosure: I am the product manager for Matillion ETL for Redshift)*

Matillion is an ELT tool - it will Extract data from your (numerous) SQL server databases and Load them, via an efficient Redshift COPY, into some staging tables (which can be stored inside Redshift in the usual way, or can be held on S3 and accessed from Redshift via Spectrum). From there you can add Transformation jobs to clean/filter/join (and much more!) into nice queryable star-schemas for your reporting users.

If the table schemas on your 40+ databases are very similar (your question doesn't clarify how you are breaking your data down into those servers - horizontal or vertical) you can parameterise the connection details in your jobs and use iteration to run them over each source database, either serially or with a level of parallelism.

Pushing down transformations to Redshift works nicely because all of those transformation queries can utilize the power of a massively parallel, scalable compute architecture. Workload Management configuration can be used to ensure ETL and User queries can happen concurrently.

Also, you may have other sources of data you want to mash-up inside your Redshift cluster, and Matillion supports many more - see https://www.matillion.com/etl-for-redshift/integrations/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS DMS for this.

Steps:

1. set up and configure DMS instance
2. set up target endpoint for redshift
3. set up source endpoints for each sql server instance see
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html
4. set up a task for each sql server source, you can specify the tables
   to copy/synchronise and you can use a transformation to specify
   which schema name(s) on redshift you want to write to.

You will then have all of the data in identical schemas on redshift.

If you want to query all those together, you can do that by wither running some transformation code inside redsshift to combine and make new tables. Or you may be able to use views.

Comment: Redshift is good at aggregate queries, not ETL. If you have to perform transformations inside Redshift the performance will be *very* bad.

Comment: Wrong, Redshift is excellent at many ETL tasks. You must sort out WLM if you have ETL running as well other usage.

Comment: Wrong wrong, unless you want to *pay for a larger cluster* to treat Redshift as a staging database.Transformation *doesn't* mean `specify which schema name(s) on redshift you want to write to`. It means combine data, cleanup, remove bad rows, split or combine columns, until you bring the data to a form appropriate for you business case, typically reporting. If you have even a moderate amount of data you can't do it piecemeal, it has to be done in a streaming fashion - that's why T comes before L. Otherwise you are talking about ELT - Extract Load Transform.

Comment: Obviously there will be incremental resource usage but the pattern is a good on! - see my comment above - research matillion's success in this field if you want some proof.

Comment: I don't think Matillion does what you think it does. It doesn't perform the transformations *inside* Redshift, ie using SQL queries. It's not the first ETL product in the world either. All do similar jobs, all face the same limitations. The eTl tools load data from the sources in a stream, transform the data as it passes then send it to the output.  The *Aggregate* transformation in *all* of them will have to cache the data for example. The same with `Distinct` which is why they are expensive

Comment: did you read https://www.matillion.com/etl-for-redshift/faq/#performance ? take a look at the 3 points there for a high level view - or use it in practice in the field to see the reality. The trouble with this tool is that sometimes the transformation SQL can get very very large very quickly if you start stringing together dozens of transformation steps. It still runs well though. I agree there is also a case for transformation outside of Redshift (of course) using traditional tools, Apache spark etc or AWS glue. there are use cases for these.

Comment: In the end Matillion will have to use whatever mechanism is available to *insert* new data into a table. Redshift provides either COPY or individual INSERT statements. There's no magic involved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163388/discussion-between-jon-scott-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: I didn't read the marketing blurb. I went straight to the technical data on the transformations. It's not the first time I work with data warehouses or Redshift. Or have to troubleshoot cascading CTEs to query badly designed Redshift tables because someone thought "we don't need no stinkin' star schemas with Redshift"

Comment: Its not marketing blurb, its simply a few lines of information explaining how matillion pushed all transformations down to redshift. Thats how it works.

Comment: `as Matillion is an ELT tool`. As I said, it doesn't do what you think it does. In such cases, yes, handcoding the CTEs may be better and faster than having the tool generate them. As long as the query doesn't end up using tons of memory and temporary storage because eg aggregations *have* to read all the data before producing output. Such approaches *do* scale worse than processing a stream of data, which is what the (more advanced) ETL tools do.